# Is this proof for divergence of harmonic series rigorous? Can it be made so?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Bartle & Sherbert, edition 4, page-97 gives the following proof:

Assume that the series converges to some $S$:

$$\implies S= 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+ \dots$$

Then they proceed to derive an inequality by converting the terms of the type $\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}$ into $\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{n}$
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+ \dots > \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right) +\dots=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \dots=S$$
They have shown $S>S$ from the assumption, hence, there's a contradiction.

But I do not like their insistence upon using the "$\dots$", as I feel like they're hiding something behind that.

If we do a similar analysis a bit more rigorously, i.e, working solely with sequences of partial sums up to a defined, fixed $n$, (instead of those dots), we have:

$$S_{2n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \dots +\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}$$
$$S_{2n} >\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right) \dots +\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \dots \frac{1}{n}=S_n \implies S_{2n} > S_{n}$$
This is *hardly* news, since the 1-harmonic is monotone increasing.

*Now* assuming that the sequence $S_n$ converges, and passing onto the limit in the above equation yields:
$$S \geq S$$ which is ***fine***?

Comment: When the pattern is clear, there's nothing unrigorous about using ellipsis. What is it you feel is being "hidden" by them?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex That's not true. Many examples of conditional convergence series leading to contradictions when not handled properly comes from that way of using ellipsis.

Comment: Of course, they can lead to errors and general confusion when not used properly, but the statement here is that terms can be grouped by $\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n}$ and you can use a strict inequality on those. Why wouldn't it be appropriate to use ellipsis here ?

Comment: @ChrisMzz. Because when dealing with series you can't just group the terms like that and expect the resulting series to have the same sum.

Comment: In fact, if a series is convergent but not absolutely convergent then for any real x you can order the series so it converges to x (!)

Comment: Sorry for insisting, but I don't understand the answer you provided. How are the terms permuted ? $\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n}$ are consecutive throughout the series, are they not ? If I misunderstand this theorem it would really help if you can clear this up for me, thank you.

Comment: We usually denote the partial sums $H_n$. If the harmonic series converged, we'd have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_{2n}-H_n)=0$, which is easily refuted. Their observation, which could do with the rigour, is that $H_{2n+2}-H_{n+1}-H_{2n}+H_n>0$, so $H_{2n}-H_n$ is an increasing positive sequence.

Comment: @ChrisMzz. The problems with series arises not only when permuting the terms, but also with grouping them in different ways (introducing parenthesis).

Comment: Here S is assumed to be a finite number. If the terms of the series are positive, absolute convergence is the same as convergence. Permuting or grouping should not matter when there is absolute convergence. And this is talking about a hypothetical S itself, which is not "$S_n$" or "$S_{2n}$"

Comment: @jjagmath - As long as the series converges, any regrouping-without-rearrangement must converge to the same limit, as the partial sums obtained by adding the groups form a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums of the original series. Admittedly, if the original series is not convergent, then such regrouping can result in a convergent series, for example $(-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) + \dots$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, we are dealing with the sequence of partial sums. And it can happen that a sequence $s_n$ diverge while one of its subsequence $s_{n_k}$ converge. And even can happen that two subsequences $s_{n_k}$ and $s_{m_k}$ converge, but to different limits. Those facts are not really important here since in this case we are beggining with a convergent sequence, and `Theorem: If a sequence converge, all of its subsequences must converge to the same limit`. **But that needs to be proved!**, and that is hidden by the use of ellipsis.

Comment: @jjagmath - that all subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit is a basic theorem about sequences that very very likely has already been discussed in the text well before it starts delving into series (though I don't have access to a copy to confirm this). So I have no hesitation to resorting to this result than I would resorting to using the result that any rearrangement of a *finite* sum does not change its value.

Comment: @PaulSinclair If the theorem has been proved before in the book then I agree that the proof in the book could be considered complete. Still, for a new student, the use of ellipsis like that without any mention to the theorems been used in the background can be misleading.

Comment: @PaulSinclair See my last comment in my answer below.

Comment: @jjagmath - My comment was only in regards to your earlier comment "The problems with series arises not only when permuting the terms, but also with grouping them in different ways". I merely pointed out that grouping without also permuting is not an issue if the original (ungrouped) series converges. I did not suggest this meant the proof in the question was adequate. And I myself pointed out that convergence of the ungrouped series was necessary. So I am at a loss about your comments to me that do not in any way address matters that I actually said.

Comment: @jjagmath is correct. What many people do not realize is that students tend to do whatever they feel like doing with no justification at all. The right question is not "Why can't we?" but "Why can we?". Students need to be taught to **not** expect anything unless proven, and to be able to clearly distinguish between wish and theorem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The estimate $S_{2n} > S_{n}$ is indeed not good enough to prove that the harmonic series is not convergent. But with a small modification one can show that $S_{2n} > a + S_{n}$ for some positive number $a$ which does not depend on $n$, and that suffices for the proof.

Concretely: For all $n\ge 2$ is
$$
\begin{align}
S_{2n}&=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \dots +\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n} \\
&>1+\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right) \dots +\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}\right) \\
&= \frac 12 + S_n \, .
\end{align}
$$
If the harmonic series were convergent with value $S$ then both $S_{2n}$ and $S_n$ would converge to $S$, and we could conclude that
$$
 S \ge \frac 12 + S
$$
which is of course impossible.

Comment: The endgame can be simplified a bit: Once you’ve shown that $S_{2n} > \frac{1}{2}+S_n$, you can immediately conclude $S_{2^k} \geq \frac{k}{2}$, giving a direct proof of divergence with a concrete lower bound on the rate.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Yes, I am aware of that. The question  (as I understand it) was how the argument “$S_{2n} > S_n \implies S \ge S \implies \sum 1/n \text{ is divergent}$” can be made rigorous, and that is what I tried to answer. – Of course there are many other proofs for the divergence of the harmonic series.

Comment: [Re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848640/is-this-proof-for-divergence-of-harmonic-series-rigorous-can-it-be-made-so#comment10332635_4848657), of course it was just a typo, but your $S \ge S$ should be $S > S$.

Comment: @LSpice Well, the original issue was that the OP interpreted Bartle & Sherbert's argument as $S_{2n}>S_n \Rightarrow S \geq S$, which does **not** imply that $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.
That's because $S_{2n}>S_n \Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{2n} \geq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$ (here $>$ became $\geq$ after taking the limit). However, what was needed for a contradiction was really $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{2n} > \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$ (with strict $>$, so they have finite difference). Bartle & Sherbert did not claim that "..." were finitely many terms, though.

Answer (score 12):

Another explanation leading to $S_{2n}>S_n+{1\over 2}$ could be
$$S_{2n}=\left (1+{1\over 2}+\ldots +{1\over n}\right )+\left ({1\over n+1}+\ldots +{1\over 2n} \right )\\
> S_n +\underbrace{{1\over 2n}+\ldots +{1\over 2n}}_{n\ {\rm terms}}=S_n+{1\over 2}$$
This method is usually applied  in proofs of the condensation test.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct. The manipulation of series like that needs some more details to be complete. In this case one needs the following theorem: if a series is absolutely convergent, then the terms of the series may be grouped (and permuted) and the sum will be the same. Since this series has only positive terms, assuming that it is convergent implies the absolute convergence and the theorem can be applied to get the contradiction.

Comment: It's probably more appropriate for me to comment here to ask this, the Riemann series theorem only mentions permuation, and the inequality is built off of terms in the same order here.

Comment: @ChrisMzz. The problems with series arises not only when permuting the terms, but also with grouping them in different ways (introducing parenthesis).

Comment: @jjagmath, how so? If we are talking about the same thing here, then the sequence of partial sums of the series with additional parentheses is a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums of the original series.

Comment: @CarstenS Yes, we are dealing with the sequence of partial sums. And it can happen that a sequence $s_n$ diverge while one of its subsequence $s_{n_k}$ converge. And even can happen that two subsequences $s_{n_k}$ and $s_{m_k}$ converge, but to different limits. Those facts are not really important here since in this case we are beggining with a convergent sequence, and `Theorem: If a sequence converge, all of its subsequences must converge to the same limit`. **But that needs to be proved!**, and that is hidden by the use of ellipsis.

Comment: Okay, but then we agree that conditional convergence is sufficient to guarantee that these grouped series all converge to the same value and that that is a simpler statement than that about reorderings. I thought that was what @ChrisMzz was interested in.

Comment: @CarstenS Yes, but not without the mention of the necessary theorem, and I don't if  ChrissMzz was aware that the theorem was been used "in the background".

Comment: Adding to my point: We already agreed that when a series is convergent then one can introduce parenthesis (group the terms of the series) and the resulting series will converge to the same limit. But then someone who is new to the subject, could think that something like changing $1+0+0+0+0 +\cdots$ can be replaced by $1 + (0) + (0) + (0) + \cdots$ (you are just introducing parenthesis) and then, since obviously $0 = 1-1$, you can replace that with $1 + (1-1) + (1-1) + (1-1)+ \cdots$ and now we are in a gray area. Can we drop the parenthesis? We begin with a convergent sequence after all.

Comment: I agree that it can confuse newcomers. If every term is nonnegative then there is no problem with the parentheses, since it's the same as absolute convergence after all. However, if you remove the parentheses in $(1-1)$ terms, it is not guaranteed to work since you'll generate negative terms.

Comment: Yes, I was aware the theorem was used in the background, and when you @jjagmath mentioned that grouping could also cause problems I realised that the series $(-1)^n$ was a perfect example of this. Thanks for the clarification you provided, it was quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not like his insistence upon using the "…", as I feel like he's hiding something behind that.

Of course they are hiding something behind that.  Mainly, it is formal notation for the sum of a series.  But the point is not to deceive, and the conclusion is not wrong.  The point is exactly to present the idea of the proof in a simple, easily digestible form, without going into all the details.  One can make mistakes by skipping a rigorous proof in such a case, but in context, it is reasonable to assume that the authors are summarizing a well known proof, as opposed to trying to be unreasonably loose.

The authors' proof sketch could indeed be filled in a bit to provide more rigor. That might go something like this:

---

Suppose that $S$ is a real number such that $S = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty{1 \over i}$.

The sum of an infinite series is the limit of its partial sums, so $S = \lim_{n \to \infty}S_n$, where $S_n = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n{1 \over i}$.

Now consider those $S_n$ where $n$ is even.  These finite sums can be regrouped to express $S_n$ in the form $S_n = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n / 2}\left({{1 \over {2i - 1}} + {1 \over {2i}}}\right)$.

If it exists (as we have assumed), the limit of all the partial sums must also be the limit of this subset of the partial sums, so we are justified in writing $S = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty}\left({{1 \over {2i - 1}} + {1 \over {2i}}}\right)$.

But observe that for every integer $i > 0$, we have that ${{1 \over {2i - 1}} > {1 \over {2i}}}$, and therefore that $\left({{1 \over {2i - 1}} + {1 \over {2i}}}\right) > \left({{1 \over {2i}} + {1 \over {2i}}}\right) = {1 \over i}$.

With every term of $S = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty}\left({{1 \over {2i - 1}} + {1 \over {2i}}}\right)$ being strictly greater than ${1 \over i}$, it follows that $S > \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over i} = S$.

But no real number is greater than itself, so there can be no real number $S$ satisfying $S = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty{1 \over i}$.  That is, the sum does not converge.

---

You might see steps in that proof that you would like to see proven themselves.  That would be fair, and you are welcome to proceed, to whatever level of detail you like.

As for your own analysis, it is neither wrong nor inconsistent with the above, but it proves a much weaker result: that if the sum of the harmonic series is a well defined real number, then that number is equal to itself (since it cannot be strictly greater).  Of course, we don't need to play with partial sums to come to that conclusion.

Comment: This is wrong. You discarded too much information. $a_n=\frac1n$ and $b_n=\frac1{2n}$ converge both to the same limit zero, but $a_n>b_n$. What is possible to say is that $$\frac1{2i-1}+\frac1{2i}=\frac1{i}+\frac1{2i(2i-1)},$$ and the second term presents a real difference at $i=1$ that becomes only larger in the accumulation of the later terms.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, (i) this is a formalization of Bartle & Sherbert's argument referenced by the OP, which conceivably could be wrong.  However, (ii) I think the argument presented here says just what you said, in less detail.  That is, that there are differences $> 0$ between corresponding terms in the two summation formulae, always favoring the second formula over the first.

Comment: "That is, that there are differences >0
 between corresponding terms in the two summation formulae" The point is that it's not sufficient to say $a_n-b_n$ is always a positive number, you have to show that there is a positive number that it's always greater than.

Comment: @Acccumulation, is there perhaps some confusion here between the terms of the sums and their series of partial sums? Consider two sums of the form $A=0+t_1+t_2+...$ and $B=1+t_1+t_2+...$. Here, $b_n−a_n$ is greater than 0 for only one pair of corresponding terms, but if these sums converge then surely $B=A+1>A$. The difference between corresponding *partial sums* must always equal or exceed some positive constant for $B>A$, but that does not require the same of the difference between corresponding *terms*.

Comment: As I said at first, reducing the current knowledge to $S_{2n}>S_n$ loses too much information. For instance this is also true if the series was over $\frac1{n^2}$ which converges, so that the limits are equal. The whole argumentation here and in the other answers is that you have to keep hold of a positive minimum for the difference.

Comment: Well, "$S_{2n}>S_{n}$" is not enough to produce a contradiction, which is also shown in the OP. But I don't think that's what Bartle & Sherbert tried to argue. 
Also, if $(a_k-b_k)>0$ for every term then that means $(a_1-b_1)>0$,  $(a_2-b_2)>0$ and so on. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_k-b_k)$ for $k>1$ is always greater than $(a_1-b_1)$ which is positive.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, in this answer, I have used the symbology $S_n$ for partial sums of $S$.  I have *not* argued that the conclusion follows from comparisons of these.  The diversion into partial sums serves only to prove that if $S$ converges then $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty}\left({{1 \over {2i - 1}} + {1 \over {2i}}}\right)$ is a valid formula for it.  Now, let $s_i = {1\over{i}}$ and $s_{i}^{'} = {1\over{2i - 1}} + {1\over{2i}}$.  Since $s_{i}^{'} > s_{i}$ for every $i$, if $\sum{s_{i}}$ and $\sum{s_{i}^{'}}$ converge, the latter must exceed the former by at least $s_{1}^{'} - s_{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\exists L: \forall \epsilon \exists N: (n>N) \rightarrow (|L-\sum_{i=0}^n a_n|<\epsilon)$

Pick $\epsilon = \frac 18$, and let $n>N$, where $N$ is an integer satisfying the requisite property above. Then $2n$ will also be greater than $N$, so $|L-\sum_{i=0}^{2n} a_n|<\epsilon$. Applying the Triangle Inequality, $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} a_n<L+\frac 18$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n a_n>L-\frac 18$.

But by the argument you cite in your question, $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} a_n> \frac 12+\sum_{i=0}^n a_n>\frac 12+L-\frac18=L+\frac38$. Thus we have $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} a_n>L+\frac38$ but also $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} a_n<L+\frac18$, wihch is a contradiction.

In summary, the definition of convergence constrains the behavior of the sum not only once we reach $N$, but also for every $n$ after $N$, including $2N$. So we can take arbitrarily large number of terms, and the argument you cite is not invalid simply because it needs a larger number of terms in one part than it has in another.

Answer (score 0):

Proposition: The harmonic series diverges.

Proof: Suppose the series converges. Let S be the series sum.

Rewrite as sums of terms with even denominator and odd denominator:
S = S_odd + S_even

Note first that S_even =  (1/2) * S.
Second, 1/(2n-1) > 1/(2n), so S_odd > S_even.

Thus, we have the contradiction that S = S_odd + S_even  >  (1/2)S +  (1/2)S = S.

I had that proof published over a quarter-century ago. See:

Michael W. Ecker, Divergence Of The Harmonic Series By Rearrangement, The College Mathematics Journal, May 1997, Vol. 28, No. 3, p. 209-210.